# Is another script hijacking jQuery(window).resize()?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, events, resize, window-resize

I'm trying the following code in Chrome and Firefox and only the NATIVE RESIZE is getting logged:

```
window.onresize = function(){ console.log( "NATIVE RESIZE" ) }

jQuery(window).resize(function(){ console.log( "JQUERY RESIZE" ) });
```

The jQuery.resize() NEVER fires. The window.onresize fires pretty much constantly as you resize the browser window (I'll implement a debounce later).

This is not the only JavaScript running within this ecosystem - this script is executing in the context of a WordPress + theme installation, so there is certainly something else in play since [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nHyMR/) works perfectly as expected.

How can I proceed (without systematically disabling the other scripts) to figure out what is hijacking jQuery.resize(). And, how can you even hijack jQuery.resize()? I would have thought that calling jQuery.resize() just adds your handler to the queue, and not completely replaces what's already there...

Comment: did you wrap the jquery in `$(function () { ... });` ?

Comment: Not in this example. why? I'm using jquery in noconflict mode...

Comment: Did you try this in separate pages or at the same time? Mixing jQuery events and native events would make them conflict.

Comment: I have some code that does exactly what yours does, and it works. The only difference I can think of is perhaps that you're not waiting for the document to be ready. Oh, like @programminginallston said.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nHyMR/

Comment: @programminginallston hmm.. does a window object need to be in a dom ready?  Because the window object contains the document object

Comment: Add a jsfiddle showing us your problem. It seems to work...

Comment: Yeah, don't need the DOMReady event if you're working on window...

Comment: @cfs dang, works for me too. So something must be hijacking my jQuery.resize(). I will edit my question, since it seems to be more specific than I thought.

Comment: @Alvaro, that's all I got! Except this is running in a complex ecosystem with all sorts of other scripts (WordPress, theme etc). So something else must be hijacking. But I don't see why/how.

Comment: @TomAuger try `console.log($._data(window,'events'));` after the jQuery event binding to see if the event is even bound

Comment: I think I found it. Seems some other script does a global jQuery.unbind( 'resize' ), which is flushing all resize handlers, before binding its own. Sketchy coding practices @EricHolmes (personal burn).

Answer (score 0):

Another script hijacked the jQuery( window ).resize() queue by doing a global unbind, like this: `jQuery( window ).unbind( 'resize' )`.

This is not a good practice, for precisely this reason. Solution: if you absolutely **must** unbind your handler, move your handler out of an anonymous function and into a namespaced function. Then, within your namespaced context, `jQuery( window ).unbind( 'resize', yourFunction )`